# Apache mod_rewrite preserving query string and adding anchor

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to create a mod_rewrite rule that redirects this:
`www.domain.com/original/`

To this with an appended anchor:
`www.domain.com/new/#something-else`

It should also preserve any query string specified in the original URL, when present. For example:
`www.domain.com/original/?key=example`

Should redirect to:
`www.domain.com/new/?key=example#something-else`

I tried using the following mod_rewrite rule with the NE and QSA flags, and even though it preserves the anchor and query string, they are rewritten in the wrong order: query string **after** anchor instead of before.

```
RewriteRule ^original https://%{HTTP_HOST}/new/$1#something-else [QSA,NE,R=301,L]
```

How can I preserve the original query string (when present) and append the anchor to the end?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I preserve the original query string (when present) and append the anchor to the end?

Flag `QSA` is not needed unless you are modifying query string in your redirect, hence that can be omitted here.

There is no need to use `https://%{HTTP_HOST}` in your rule because source and redirected domains are same.

`$1` will be empty because you're not capturing any text in your pattern.

You may use this redirect rule:

```sh
# when query string is non-empty
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule ^original/?$ /new/?%{QUERY_STRING}#something-else [NC,NE,R=302,L]

# when query string is empty
RewriteRule ^original/?$ /new/#something-else [NC,NE,R=302,L]
```

Once you verify it is working fine, replace `R=302` to `R=301` (permanent redirect)

Comment: It probably makes sense to start testing with a `R=302` temporary redirection and only change that to a `R=301` permanent redirection once you are certain that everything works as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this doesn't work. The redirect ends up as `/new/#something-else?query_string` which is not a valid URL. The anchor should always go **after** the query string like `/new/?query_string#something-else`. Is there a way to force mod_rewrite to place these elements in the right order?

Comment: ok can you try: `RewriteRule ^original/?$ /new/?%{QUERY_STRING}#something-else [NC,NE,R=302,L]`

Comment: Thanks, that works better, but still has one problem: the query string should be optional, and if no query string is specified in the incoming URL, it's currently ending up like `/new/?#something-else` . How can I get rid of the "?" when the query string isn't specified?